# How do I find the calling stored procedure/function

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

We have implemented a global error logger for all `SQL` Stored procedures and functions.  When a procedure/function encounters an `SQLEXCEPTION` or `SQLWARNING`, we call a global error logger and execute a `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS` statement.  Part of the data we need to have is the procedure name that failed.  I am not seeing that in the `GET DIAGNOSTICS` available return values (`ROUTINE_NAME` and `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` are returned conditionally, and I need it always).

We are currently using the `QWVRCSTK API`, but I would assume that SQL has a method if providing this data.  Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: for SQL server, it will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086973/recording-sql-server-call-stack-when-reporting-errors  SQL does not lend itself well to exception handling.  You are handicapping yourself by not doing it client side.

Comment: SPECIFIC_SCHEMA may have what you're looking for but it too is only returned conditionally.  I myself use the call stack API.

Comment: Thanks you all, we actually just had the calling procedure pass in its name.  Not ideal, but simple enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**Retrieve Job Information (QUSRJOBI) API**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/qusrjobi.htm) can return the qualified name of the object that is running the current (most recent) SQL statement in a job. Use format `JOBI0900` to access a job's SQL information.

You'd want to create an **external** stored procedure to call the API. (If you try to do it as a SQL stored proc, the problem would be that a statement in the SP itself would be the current one; and you want the current SQL to be in the calling proc.)

When this SP is called, the "current" SQL should be the CALL statement from back in the calling procedure. (I hope that makes sense.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select @@ProcID
```

Returns the object identifier(ID) of the current Transact-SQL module. A Transact-SQL module can be a stored procedure, user-defined function, or trigger.

From there you can :

```
select OBJECT_NAME(@@ProcID)
```

Which will return the name of the object.

.

Comment: The question is about DB2 on IBM i.