How to Capture Detailed Error Information and Send Notification in SQL Server Maintenance Plan?
I'm working on a SQL Server maintenance plan and need to capture detailed error information and send a notification email when a job fails. I've created a stored procedure to send the email, but I'm having trouble getting detailed error messages in the notification.
Here is my current setup:
Stored Procedure for Sending Notifications:
USE [master]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SendJobFailureNotification]
(
    @JobName NVARCHAR(128),
    @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @Body = N'The job ' + @JobName + N' has failed with the following error: ' + @ErrorMessage + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                'Error Number: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS NVARCHAR(10)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                'Severity: ' + CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS NVARCHAR(10)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                'State: ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS NVARCHAR(10)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                'Procedure: ' + ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), 'N/A') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                'Line Number: ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR(10));

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'BackupAlertsProfile',
        @recipients = 'your.email@example.com',
        @subject = 'SQL Server Job Failure',
        @body = @Body;
END;
GO


Job Step With Error Handling:
BEGIN TRY
    -- Start the maintenance plan job
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = N'TestMaintenancePlan.Subplan_1'; 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Log detailed error information and send notification
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    
    -- Calling the stored procedure to send a failure notification email
    EXEC dbo.SendJobFailureNotification @JobName = N'TestMaintenancePlan.Subplan_1', @ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage;
    
    -- Raise the error again to ensure the job shows as failed
    RAISERROR('Job Failed: %s', 16, 1, @ErrorMessage);
END CATCH;


So what is your question?

Here are some other functions you should call to provide more info about the error:         ERROR_NUMBER()
,ERROR_SEVERITY()
,ERROR_STATE() AS
,ERROR_PROCEDURE()
,ERROR_LINE()

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086973/recording-sql-server-call-stack-when-reporting-errors

You won't get any errors that way (well, except errors if job is already started or you don't have permissions), because sp_start_job only queues the job start, the actual job is run asynchroniously in sql server agent a bit later. To get execution errors, you have to do a lot more work. I'd probably just run separate job which executes a procedure which gathers errors from msdb..sysjobhistory and friends. If you're using db mail, i think sql server agent can itself generate error emails, check the settings under the agent job
