# Execute Statements in a Transaction - Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, transactions, execute

i need to update a database where some of the table have changed (columns have been added). I want to perform this action in a proper transaction. If the code executes without any problem then i will commit the changes otherwise i will rollback the database back to its original state.

I want to do something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ...Execute some sql statements here
COMMIT TRANSACTION (When every thing goes well)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION (When something goes wrong)
```

Please tell me what is the best way to do this i know there is a @@TranCount variable but dont know its exact purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: please see: Nested stored procedures containing TRY CATCH ROLLBACK pattern?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Begin Transaction

Alter Table dbo.MyTable
Add Col1 varchar(50)

If @@Error = 0

   Begin
    Commit Transaction
   End
Else
   Begin
    Rollback Transaction
   End
```

@@Error gets reset after each SQL Statement so you must check it  immediately after each statement has been executed to check for any errors.