# tsql transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In order to wrap stored procedure in a transaction I add the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_ORD_InsertTextField]
    //PARAMS
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    //STP BODY

    COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         ROLLBACK

      DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int
      SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
             @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

      RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Is there any shorter way that does the same? this is a huge code block for "just" handle a transaction..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is pretty much it.

You can hide the @ErrMsg processing behind a stored proc or UDF, and you don't need @ErrSeverity processing. It is normally 16 which is "user defined error"

See my answer here too please: [Nested stored procedures containing TRY CATCH ROLLBACK pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern/2074139#2074139)

Comment: @gbn: What is the reason for NO COUNT in your answer?

Comment: @Naor: The "xx rows affected" returns an extra recordset to the client. It also breaks some ORMs and some clients. See my question here please http://stackoverflow.com/q/1483732/27535

Comment: @gbn: So you put SET NOCOUNT in every stored procedure you have?

Comment: @Naor: yes, and SET XACT_ABORT ON too

Comment: @gbn: I mean, you put SET NOCOUNT in every stored procedure even if it doesn't contains transaction?

Comment: @Naor: yes, and SET XACT_ABORT ON too. A transaction has nothing to so with SET NOCOUNT ON