# Is this good writen transaction in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions, scope

This is the first time that I use transactions and I just wonder am I make this right. Should I change something?
I insert post(wisp). When insert post I need to generate ID in commentableEntity table and insert that ID in wisp table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateWisp]
@m_UserId uniqueidentifier,
@m_WispTypeId int,
@m_CreatedOnDate datetime,
@m_PrivacyTypeId int,
@m_WispText nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @wispId int

    INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Wisps
    (UserId,WispTypeId,CreatedOnDate,PrivacyTypeId,WispText)
    VALUES
    (@m_UserId,@m_WispTypeId,@m_CreatedOnDate,@m_PrivacyTypeId,@m_WispText)

    if @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK            
            RAISERROR ('Error in adding new wisp.', 16, 1)
            RETURN
        END

    SELECT @wispId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_CommentableEntity
    (ItemId)
    VALUES
    (@wispId)

    if @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK            
            RAISERROR ('Error in adding commentable entity.', 16, 1)
            RETURN
        END

    DECLARE @ceid int

    select @ceid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE dbo.tbl_Wisps SET CommentableEntityId = @ceid WHERE WispId = @wispId

    if @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK            
            RAISERROR ('Error in adding wisp commentable entity id.', 16, 1)
            RETURN
        END

COMMIT
```

Using try/catch based on @gbn answer:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateWisp]
@m_UserId uniqueidentifier,
@m_WispTypeId int,
@m_CreatedOnDate datetime,
@m_PrivacyTypeId int,
@m_WispText nvarchar(200)
AS

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @starttrancount int

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @starttrancount = @@TRANCOUNT

    IF @starttrancount = 0
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        DECLARE @wispId int

        INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Wisps
        (UserId,WispTypeId,CreatedOnDate,PrivacyTypeId,WispText)
        VALUES
        (@m_UserId,@m_WispTypeId,@m_CreatedOnDate,@m_PrivacyTypeId,@m_WispText)

        SELECT @wispId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_CommentableEntity
        (ItemId)
        VALUES
        (@wispId)

        DECLARE @ceid int

        select @ceid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        UPDATE dbo.tbl_Wisps SET CommentableEntityId = @ceid WHERE WispId = @wispId

    IF @starttrancount = 0 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 AND @starttrancount = 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RAISERROR ('Error in adding new wisp', 16, 1)
END CATCH
GO
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd use TRY/CATCH since SQL Server 2005+

Your rollback goes into the CATCH block but your code looks good otherwise (using SCOPE_IDENTITY() etc). I'd also use `SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON`

This is my template: [Nested stored procedures containing TRY CATCH ROLLBACK pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern/2074139#2074139)

Edit:

- This allows for nested transactions as per DeveloperX's answer
- This template also allows for higher level transactions as per Randy's comment

Comment: Hi, I added new code based on your template in question. Please confirm that it is fine so I can close this question ;)

Answer (score 1):

i think its not good all the time ,but if you want to use more than one stored procedure same time its not good be cause each stored procedure handles the transaction independently

but in this case,you should use try catch block , for exception handling , and preventing keeping transaction open on when an exception raising

Comment: see the link in my answer please: easy to nest them

Comment: Yes,my answer was about putting transaction in a stored procedure,in this case your answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

I've never considered it a good idea to put transactions in a stored procedure. I think it's much better to start a transaction at a higher level so that can better coordinate multiple database (e.g. stored procedure) calls and treat them all as a single transaction.

Comment: Then you require MSDTC involvement. Shouldn't each database call for write be atomic where possible? See my answer too please for a template that handles it anyway.