# IF, RAISERROR & RETURN in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, return, raiserror

I have a stored procedure, `PROC`, which receives some parameters. If one of them, `@ID`, is not null, a given stored procedure, `PROC_A`, must be executed. Otherwise, `PROC_B` must be executed. The problem is that both of them may issue a `RAISERROR`, which I want to propagate through the call stack to be displayed at the client application. However, that `RAISERROR` won't stop the rest of the `PROC` stored procedure as it should, and, since I am using an `IF` clause, checking `IF ( @@ERROR <> 0 ) RETURN` isn't an option either. My only choice seems to be using a `TRY...CATCH` block to wrap the `IF` clause and rethrow the `RAISERROR` from within the `CATCH` block, which is awkwards because then I will have to cache `ERROR_MESSAGE()`, `ERROR_SEVERITY()` and  `ERROR_STATE()` and use `RAISERROR` once again.

Isn't there really any more elegant way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use a `TRY - CATCH` block and echo back the original error, which isn't that hard to do:

```
BEGIN TRY
    --used in the CATCH block to echo the error back
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(400), @ErrorNumber int, @ErrorSeverity int, @ErrorState int, @ErrorLine int

    --Your stuff here

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    --your error code/logging here

    --will echo back the complete original error message
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = N'Error %d, Line %d, Message: '+ERROR_MESSAGE(),@ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),@ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),@ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),@ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE()
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorNumber,@ErrorLine)

END CATCH
```

Also, it is best practice to have your entire procedure in a `TRY - CATCH`, and not just the external procedure calls.

Comment: +1 And I'll shamelessly link to my template http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern/2074139#2074139