# What Order should I Call @@ROWCOUNT/@@ERROR

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am inserting a number or rows into a table using INSERT with SELECT.
After the transaction, I want to store both the @@ROWCOUNT and @@ERROR values into locallay declared variables.

```
INSERT SubscriberList (PublicationId, SubscriberId)
SELECT @PublicationId, S.SubscriberId
FROM Subscribers S

SET @NoRows = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @ErrorCode = @@ERROR
```

I wasn't sure if this was valid in as much if I call one, will I negate the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set them both at once:

`SELECT @NoRows = @@ROWCOUNT, @ErrorCode = @@ERROR`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @JNK's answer...

I never use @@ERROR now because of TRY/CATCH

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN

    INSERT SubscriberList (PublicationId, SubscriberId)
    SELECT @PublicationId, S.SubscriberId
    FROM Subscribers S

    SET @NoRows = @@ROWCOUNT

    ... do more inserts, updates etc

    COMMIT TRAN

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    SET @ErrorCode = ERROR_NUMBER()
    RAISERROR  ...
END CATCH
```

Comment: +1 - I was assuming SQL Server 2000 for some reason though OP doesn't state it.

Comment: Thank you - I had not seen this construct before, but it looks much better.

Comment: @Neilski: You're welcome. For more  info on TRY/CATCH, see my answer here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern/2074139#2074139