# Begin Transaction ... Commit Transaction Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, transactions

i have a question regarding using Transaction. Consider this code:

```
declare @trans_name varchar(max) = 'Append'
begin tran @trans_name
    insert into SIDB_Module
    (module_name, module_description, modulelevel, parentid, issystem, iscurrent)
    values
    (@module_name, @module_description, @modulelevel, @parentid, @issystem, 1)
    set @moduleid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    declare @id int = OBJECT_ID('SIDB_Module')
    exec usp_M_SIDB_TransactionInformation_App_Append
        @moduleid, id, 'append' ,@createdby_userid
if @@ERROR <> 0
rollback tran @trans_name
commit tran @trans_name
```

does transaction still apply on this.. even the next insert query is on the other stored procedure??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the call to `usp_M_SIDB_TransactionInformation_App_Append` is part of the transaction

Note: your error handling is "old style" (using @@ERROR) from SQL Server 2000 and will generate errors (error 266) if the inner proc rolls back or commits.

For more, see [Nested stored procedures containing TRY CATCH ROLLBACK pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern/2074139#2074139)