# Update multiple table at the same time using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I  have two tables, I need to update both table at same time.

Tables:

- BillMaster (ID, Date, CustomerName)
- BillDetail (BillDetailID, BillID, ItemName, Rate, Quantity, Amount)

`ID` is the primary key and `BillID` is a foreign key.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: yes sorry im new..sql-server

Comment: @user19124549 Kindly give more details and also provide sample data and desired result for faster and better solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stored procedure to update multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444923/stored-procedure-to-update-multiple-tables)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What does C# and .NET have to do with this? Please explain your situation, what code do you have so far?

Comment: Can you remove c# and .net tags from this question as they are not relevant?

Answer (score 3):

> to update both table at same time

It's not typically done that way; instead you update one table then the other in a transaction, and when the transaction completes both tables are changed, or if the transaction rolls back then both tables are unchanged. It thus *looks like* both updates have been done at the same time even though they are done by two update statements occurring one after the other

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE BillMaster SET ... WHERE ID = @ID;
UPDATE BillDetail SET ... WHERE BillID = @ID;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```