# Can I use T-SQL try-catch in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

In **ADO.NET** we have methods for starting a transaction, reading the query results, etc.
My question is, will such T-sql statements as `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and particularly `TRY-CATCH` work if I just include them to command-text and then `ExecuteNonQuery`?

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = 
@"BEGIN TRY
    SELECT TOP 1 [id] FROM myTable;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber;
END CATCH;"

var result = mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(); // or just  mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

**PS:** I know, I can just test this myself.
But I am asking this as SO. So that afterwards someone like me will be able to just google that. So, obviously, I don't expect answers like 'why not just try'. Thank you.

Comment: o yeah, I did expect the downvotes.

Comment: Actually, you _should_ try it and post the results as an answer. That's why the `Answer your own question` checkbox on the ask a question page exists.

Comment: I will, if nobody does. Although, it is more up to me what I should and what I shoudn't

Comment: Sure, but don't be surprised if this attitude generates bad responses ;)

Comment: Sure, I am not surprised. I expected this, as I said. Altough I believe this question may be useful for someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any valid `T-SQL` or a stored procedure are valid for `SqlCommand.CommandText`.  So in short, yes you can if you are using `SQL Server 2005` or greater. However it would be best to use this in a stored procedure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext.aspx

Comment: Provided that the version of SQL Server being used supports TRY/CATCH.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (with ExecuteScalar)

But it adds no value because you should have .net error handling anyway. Let's say you have a varchar from the SELECT but int from the CATCH block too: you now have 2 different datatypes to consume.

TRY/CATCH is more intended for stored procedures and to handle transaction, as per [Nested stored procedures containing TRY CATCH ROLLBACK pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern/2074139#2074139)