# Does SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition support nested transaction?

Tags: sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 R2 supports Nested transaction but I am using SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition. Please let me know whether it supports nested transaction?

Comment: *SQL Server 2008 R2 supports Nested transaction* - that's wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No version of SQL Server supports nested transactions. It appears to, but it doesn't

Why?

- `ROLLBACK` can rollback all transactions
- Some errors "doom" the transaction stack
- `SET XACT_ABORT ON` does an implicit rollback

So even with savepoints and named transactions, you still can't truly nest. For example, the links below invalidate this pattern with savepoints: http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/ . I'd hate to rely on this because you really need `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in SQL Server

Hence my answer here to enable stored proc nesting: [Nested stored procedures containing TRY CATCH ROLLBACK pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern/2074139#2074139)

This links onto the authoritative Paul S. Randal: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt reply.