# Recommendations regarding nested transactions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, nested-transactions

I have some "base operation" stored procedures, like `BookAVehicle` and `UnBookAVehicle`. They are both in a transaction.

But now I need to have a somewhat more complex stored procedure: `RescheduleBooking`. It also needs to be transactional.

Now, from within `ResceduleBooking` I want to call `BookAVehicle`, and in this case I don't want the inner transaction to rollback.

But when I call `BookAVehicle` directly, I want to keep the rollback.

Any suggestion on how to do this elegantly?

I was thinking of something along the lines of having a "wrapper" stored procedure that as a parameter takes the name of a stored procedure and only contains a transaction and a call to the parameter stored procedure.

So when I call it "directly" I call:

```
TransactionWrapper(BookAVehicleWithoutTrans)
```

and when I call it from another transaction I call:

```
RescheduleBooking -> BookAVehicleWithoutTrans
```

Comment: It's a little dirty secret: SQL Server *appears* to support nested transactions - but it really does not. It's a bit of "eye-wash" on the developers - if you roll back inside a nested transaction, **all** transactions currently running will be rolled back. See [Paul Randal's SQL Server DBA Myth-a-day post](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/) on that topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested stored procedures containing TRY CATCH ROLLBACK pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern) This uses the link from @marc_s and deals with nested procs that maintain the transaction consistency no matter how nested

Comment: Thank you, it seems to fit the bill perfectly

Comment: marc_s I know of rollback of the nested transaction, I'm sorry if that was not evident from my post

Answer (score 1):

When you do a BEGIN TRANSACTION an internal counter is incremented @@TRANCOUNT. ROLLBACK TRANSACTION will rollback all BEGIN TRANSACTIONS setting @@TRANCOUNT to 0. Doing a commit transaction will only decrement @@TRANCOUNT, it will do a full commit when @@TRANCOUNT is 1 before setting it to 0.

With that in mind, Assuming you have paired BEGIN and COMMIT TRANSACTIONS in your Book and UnBook procedures I would do the RescheduleBooking procedure something like the following which will maintain the first book even if the unbook fails...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RescheduleBooking ...
AS
BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY
         BEGIN TRANSACTION
         EXEC BookAVehicle ...
         COMMIT TRANSACTION
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
         IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         BEGIN
             ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
         END
         RETURN
      END CATCH;

   -- If the unbook fails the booking above will still stay.
      BEGIN TRY
         BEGIN TRANSACTION
         EXEC UnBookAVehicle ...
         COMMIT TRANSACTION
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
         IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         BEGIN
             ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
         END
         RETURN
      END CATCH;
END
```