# Need Clarification on Transaction SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I read this Stackoverflow question
[Nested stored procedures containing TRY CATCH ROLLBACK pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073737/nested-stored-procedures-containing-try-catch-rollback-pattern/2074139#2074139)

I'm in need of clarification on Transaction template what **gbn** have answered.
I couldn't comment and ask there.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Name]
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @starttrancount int

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @starttrancount = @@TRANCOUNT

    IF @starttrancount = 0
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

       [...Perform work, call nested procedures...]

    IF @starttrancount = 0 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 AND @starttrancount = 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RAISERROR [rethrow caught error using @ErrorNumber, @ErrorMessage, etc]
END CATCH
GO
```

My Question is!

Why to use ?

> SELECT @starttrancount = @@TRANCOUNT , rather than using @@TRANCOUNT directly??

and why to check this?

> IF @starttrancount = 0
>          BEGIN TRANSACTION
>
> IF @starttrancount = 0 
>         COMMIT TRANSACTION

I'm new to transaction , explanation with example  would be so helpfull.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> IF @starttrancount = 0 BEGIN TRANSACTION
>
> IF @starttrancount = 0 COMMIT TRANSACTION
> ```

These are used because, the @starttrancount guaranteed to let only the outer most stored procedure to use transaction, so that only one transaction exists.

Example: We want to execute outer most procedure, then the transaction must be used in outer most procedure only.

Outer Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_outer
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @starttrancount int

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @starttrancount = @@TRANCOUNT -- Initially @@TRANSCOUNT =0

    IF @starttrancount = 0
        BEGIN TRANSACTION     -- @@TRANSCOUNT =1

       EXEC sp_inner  -- Inner Procedure is called with @@TRANSCOUNT =1 
                      -- so that Transaction in inner procedure will not be used. 
                      -- Per Transaction is exists.

    IF @starttrancount = 0 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION    -- @@TRANSCOUNT = 0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 AND @starttrancount = 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  -- If Error occurs Rollback takes place.
    RAISERROR [rethrow caught error using @ErrorNumber, @ErrorMessage, etc]
END CATCH
GO
```

2.Inner Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_inner
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @starttrancount int

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @starttrancount = @@TRANCOUNT  -- @@TRANCOUNT =1

    IF @starttrancount = 0 
        BEGIN TRANSACTION   -- Skipped

       [...Perform work, call nested procedures...]

    IF @starttrancount = 0 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION  -- Skipped
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 AND @starttrancount = 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION -- if Error Caught Roll back does not happen here
    RAISERROR [rethrow caught error using @ErrorNumber, @ErrorMessage, etc] -- Error thrown to outer stored procedure.
END CATCH
GO
```

---

> why  SELECT @starttrancount = @@TRANCOUNT , rather than using
>   @@TRANCOUNT directly??

Since @@TRANSCOUNT scope exists in both the stored procedures, for maintaining values within the procedure's scope
@starttrancount variable is used.