# What Happens To a Query If It Times Out?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a query that is sent to my SQL-Server database, it takes more than 30 seconds, and my program throws an SQL Query Timeout exception.  Is the query still chugging along on my database or does it get terminated as soon as the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> A client signals a query timeout to
> the server using an attention event.
> An attention event is simply a
> distinct type of TDS packet a SQL
> Server client can send to it.  In
> addition to connect/disconnect, T-SQL
> batch, and RPC events, a client can
> signal an attention to the server.  An
> attention tells the server to cancel
> the connection's currently executing
> query (if there is one) as soon as
> possible.  An attention doesn't
> rollback open transactions, and it
> doesn't stop the currently executing
> query on a dime -- the server aborts
> whatever it was doing for the
> connection at the next available
> opportunity.  Usually, this happens
> pretty quickly, but not always.

Source [There's no such thing as a query timeout...](https://web.archive.org/web/20100716183823/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/10/20/483015.aspx)

Bob Ward also talks about this when discussing the new `query_abort` extended event in the [Data Exposed: SQL Server 2022 Hidden Gems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vw86u05SDjc) video series.

- The worker thread executing the query is busy so the client sends an Out of Band Attention packet where it is picked up by a separate worker.
- This second worker marks the query as aborted. The original worker checks periodically to see if it is marked to have been aborted
- If it is then it performs any needed cleanup and only then fires the attention event.

This terminology is slightly different than in the original source in that the attention *event* itself is distinguished from the attention *packet* but the gist is still the same.

[image]

NB: The image above is taken from the above linked video. Note that whilst *statement* rollback is automatic (and you won't end up with half an `UPDATE` for example if the statement is aborted before completion) the rollback behaviour for any outer transaction will depend on the `XACT_ABORT` setting.

Answer (score 4):

When the client decides that the *command* has run long enough, it issues an "Abort". The query simply stops running in the database.

Any CATCH block won't be hit, transactions will be left open and locks can still remain allocated after this, even if the connection is closed because "close" means "return to connection pool".

If you expect a lot of Command Timeouts then consider using [SET XACT_ABORT ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917773/do-i-really-need-to-use-set-xact-abort-on/919279#919279) ([and this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917773/do-i-really-need-to-use-set-xact-abort-on/919279#919279)) that *will* release locks and rollback transactions. or fix the code...

Comment: You said "The query simply stops running in the database"; Martin Smith's answer said "it doesn't stop the currently executing query on a dime -- the server aborts whatever it was doing for the connection at the next available opportunity".  Which is correct?

Comment: Same result, different language. My "stop'" may be delayed based on server load, in-flight IO, whatever WAITs are in play etc

Answer (score 1):

> Before executing a query, SQL Server
>   estimates how much memory it needs to
>   run and tries to reserve this amount
>   of memory from the buffer pool. If the
>   reservation succeeds the query is
>   executed immediately. If there is not
>   enough memory readily available from
>   the buffer pool, then the query is put
>   into a queue with a timeout value,
>   where the timeout value is guided by
>   the query cost. The basic rule is:
>   higher the estimated cost is, larger
>   the time out value is. **When the
>   waiting time of this query exceeds the
>   timeout value, a time out error is
>   thrown and the query is removed from
>   the queue.**

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlqueryprocessing/archive/2006/11/14/query-execution-timeouts-in-sql-server-part-1-of-2.aspx)

Comment: The mention of 30 seconds in the question indicates that the OP is asking about command timeouts (from the client) not memory grant timeouts or lock timeouts.

Comment: The memory grant timeout is a different thing from a ADO.Net client request timeout, which is the 30 seconds the OP is referring to

Answer (score 0):

If you get a SQL timeout then SQL has stopped, however web applications can time out and the SQL query can continue.

Answer (score -3):

Usually when it times out it means the connection has died, meaning the query has not been sent to the database, most database support Transactions where you can start a transaction, run your queries, and if your happy you can commit them.

Example:

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE  authors
   SET  au_fname = 'John'
WHERE   au_id = '172-32-1176'

UPDATE  authors
   SET  au_fname = 'Marg'
WHERE   au_id = '213-46-8915'

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: In this case, the connection is still open, but the database is under a heavy load, causing queries to take a long time.

Comment: Are you talking about connection timeout or something? That is different from command timeout.

Comment: My point is that if he doing connections to a server and he need's to make sure that they go threw to the actual database, using transactions will help prevent errors that can sometimes be caused by timeout's

Comment: Your first sentence talks about "meaning the query has not been sent to the database" which would indicate some problem with the connection itself to me? Then when it stops trying to connect will be governed by the connection timeout property. The command timeout occurs when running a time consuming batch and is implemented by the client libraries. [They vary in how they handle open transactions](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-II.html#timeout)

Comment: -1 for utter confusion. A transaction will be left open on command timeout