# Is using commit in a transaction enough?

Tags: transactions, sql-server-2000

Is using `Commit` in a `transaction` enough or I should use `rollback` too.

```
tabel1
  name   nvarchar(10)
  family nvarchar(20)

table 2 
    name nvarchar(10)
    family nvarchar(20) not null

begin transaction
insert into table2 (name) values('john')
insert into table1 (name,family) values('Joe','Lando')
commit transaction
```

as you see the first statement has error. should I use rollback somewhere?

Comment: How do you run the script? Are the table definitions part of the script (in that case they are 1. incorrect and 2. outside the transaction)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip ROLLBACK if you use [SET XACT_ABORT ON (SQL Server 2000 link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259192%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
begin transaction
insert into table2 (name) values('john')
insert into table1 (name,family) values('Joe','Lando')
commit transaction
```

From the link:

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.

Now, if you don't use it you **need** rollback. Or close your connection.

One useful side effect of SET XACT_ABORT ON is that after a client CommandTimeout event, locks are released and the transactions rolled back. Otherwise, it doesn't happen until the connection is *hard* removed from SQL Server: it can stay open because of pooling.

Your bible should be ["Error Handling in SQL 2000 – a Background" by  Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html): read it. And on SO: [Do I really need to use "SET XACT_ABORT ON"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/917773/27535)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I doubt that stored procedure will actually compile because it will recognise that table2 does not have a 'family' field.

Secondly, it is probably advisable to incorporate some form of checking for your own sanity, but in any case, SQL server will rollback automatically on error.