# Why does SQL Server default XACT_ABORT to OFF? Can it be set to ON globally?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, xact-abort

I understand the purpose of [SET XACT_ABORT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql) command:

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a
>   run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.
>
> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL
>   statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction
>   continues processing. Depending upon the severity of the error, the
>   entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF.
>   OFF is the default setting.

In general, the scenarios where one would want to continue processing a transaction if error would be outnumbered by the scenarios where one would want to rollback the entire transaction if error, because I often hear DBAs and blogs recommending to keep `SET XACT_ABORT ON` to avoid running into inconsistent transaction results. I have seen all our stored procedures also have `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, as part of the templated-code.

Quesions:

1. If most of the use cases require `XACT_ABORT` to be `ON`, what would have lead SQL Server to default it to `OFF`? Would defaulting `XACT_ABORT` to `ON` had added any overhead to SQL Server transaction processing?
2. The `SET XACT_ABORT` command affect only the current sessions. I know I can make SSMS default to `SET XACT_ABORT ON` from `SSMS > Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced` as shown in this image:
   [image]
   But this is limited to only for the SQL statements running through SSMS and does not help with stored procedures called through application code/SSIS packages . For those procedures I still have to repeat `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in every procedure. Is there any way `XACT_ABORT` can be set to `ON` at database level? Any other ways I can set the `XACT_ABORT` globally and don't have to worry about it every time?

Comment: You can issue a SET XXX ON/OFF over the active connection whenever you like and the option will apply to the whole session

Comment: [Why isn't SET XACT_ABORT ON the default behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956856/why-isnt-set-xact-abort-on-the-default-behavior)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `XACT_ABORT ON` as a global default connection setting at the server level, although the command is a bit obscure:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'user options', N'16384'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-options-server-configuration-option) for details.

The option can also be set through SSMS Object Explorer > Server Properties > Connections:

[image]