# What hanging transaction in tempdb mean?

Tags: sql-server, sqltransaction, tempdb

I'm trying to troubleshoot what is causing timeouts when querying specific table in production.

I suspected that there are some uncommitted transactions, so I ran following query:

```sql
SELECT trans.session_id AS [SESSION ID]
    ,ESes.host_name AS [HOST NAME]
    ,login_name AS [Login NAME]
    ,trans.transaction_id AS [TRANSACTION ID]
    ,tas.name AS [TRANSACTION NAME]
    ,tas.transaction_begin_time AS [TRANSACTION BEGIN TIME]
    ,tds.database_id AS [DATABASE ID]
    ,DBs.name AS [DATABASE NAME]
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions tas
JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions trans ON (trans.transaction_id = tas.transaction_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_tran_database_transactions tds ON (tas.transaction_id = tds.transaction_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.databases AS DBs ON tds.database_id = DBs.database_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS ESes ON trans.session_id = ESes.session_id
WHERE ESes.session_id IS NOT NULL
```

It returned two rows with the same `[Session ID]`, one for database name `tempdb`, second for my application's database:

```
SESSION ID, Login Name, ... TRANSACTION BEGIN TIME, DATABASE NAME,
218,        MyAppSQLUser,   15 minutes ago,         tempdb
218,        MyAppSQLUser,   ...,                    MyDatabase
```

`KILL 218` solved the timeouts

Does the tempdb row indicates something? Why it's event there

What are next steps? How can I trace the transaction to my source for in the future, so I can find out, what's causing it?

Comment: Someone opened a transaction and forgot to close it. Check the application code for missing `using` or `finally` to ensure transactions get closed. Also set `XACT_ABORT ON` for all sessions https://stackoverflow.com/a/43200786/14868997

Comment: Is it normal, that there's transaction in tempdb? I'm not using stored procedures as far as I know

Comment: Probably someone created a temp table in a transaction.