# How to catch error for a transaction in T-SQL for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In SQL Server, you need to check error for each SQL statement. For example if I have 3 updates in one transaction, I need some code like:

```
declare @HasError int
begin tran
Update tab1 set ....
Set  @HasError = @@error;
Update tab2 set ...
Set  @HasError = @@error;
Update tab3 set ...
Set  @HasError = @@error;

If @HasError<>0
  rollback tran;
else
 commit tran;
```

Any other solution for this case with more simple code? for instance, something like c# style:

```
   begin tran
    try
    {
      Update tab1 set ....    
      Update tab2 set ...
      Update tab3 set ...
      commit tran;
    }catch(error){
       rollback tran;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.
Have a look at [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: @KentZhou - you should also upvote answers that best addresses your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Click here to see => Why do I really need to use SET XACT_ABORT ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917773/do-i-really-need-to-use-set-xact-abort-on)** ?

**[Click here to see How SET NOCOUNT ON Improves SQL Server Stored Procedure Performance](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1226/set-nocount-on-improves-sql-server-stored-procedure-performance/)**

```
Begin Try
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    Set XACT_ABORT ON
    Begin Tran
        --Your Query
    Commit Tran
End Try

Begin Catch
    RollBack Tran
    Select ERROR_MESSAGE() as Msg, ERROR_NUMBER() as Num
End Catch
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a try catch syntax as you would in c#

```
 BEGIN TRY
    -- ....
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
    -- ....
 END CATCH
```

Comment: And don't just rollback, return the error to the user and even better log it in an error table. If you put information about the error into a table variable, that does not get rolled back and you can then insert to a table. Having the error information stored is invaluable in figuring out what went wrong.