# How to make SET XACT_ABORT ON rollback the transaction?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, xact-abort

Based on the [Books Online documentation of `SET XACT_ABORT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx), i get the impression that if a T-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back:

> ### Remarks
>
> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.

Testing this in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
PRINT 'TranCount befor an error = '+CAST(@@Trancount AS varchar(50))

DROP TABLE QuertyAsdf

PRINT 'TranCount after an error = '+CAST(@@Trancount AS varchar(50))
```

Gives the output:

```
TranCount befor an error = 1
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 6
Cannot drop the table 'QwertyAsdf', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
TranCount after an error = 1
```

i was also under the impression that [`SET XACT_ABORT ON` terminates the batch if there's an error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1150069/12597):

> SET XACT_ABORT ON instructs SQL Server to rollback the entire transaction and abort the batch when a run-time error occurs.

That sounds handy. How can i make it do that too?

Comment: ["when XACT_ABORT is ON, not all errors terminate the batch ... Compilation errors (which normally terminate the scope) do not terminate the batch."](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#XACT_ABORT)

Comment: @MartinSmith Presumably this is not a compilation error, as it passes compilation and begins executing the batch

Comment: Generally speaking statements that reference non existent objects are subject to deferred compile. Not sure if this is the case for DDL statements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917773/do-i-really-need-to-use-set-xact-abort-on/919279#919279

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL Server only rollback transactions when Severity level greater or equals 16.

See example:

```
Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ORC_ORCAMENTO' whenIDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Test on SQL Server 2008 R2

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
PRINT 'TranCount befor an error = '+CAST(@@Trancount AS varchar(50))
insert into ORC_ORCAMENTO (ORCID, ORCNOME, ORCATIVO) VALUES (1, 'TESTE_ALEXP', 0);
PRINT 'TranCount after an error = '+CAST(@@Trancount AS varchar(50))
```

Returns

```
TranCount befor an error = 1
Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ORC_ORCAMENTO' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
TranCount after an error = 0
```

See Microsoft Error Message Levels on

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors

Answer (score 1):

When you use xact abort on, in the `try` `catch` statement, you can manually raise an error to make the transaction roll back.

```
set xact_abort on;

begin try
    ...dml statements here....

if conditions here...
    raiseerror(....);

end try
begin catch

end catch
```