# Sql Transaction doesn't do complete rollback

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transactions, rollback

I am seeing some strange behavior which has occurred on random basis. 
Here's what my store procedure basically does.

```
begin try
        begin tran
        insert into table1
        update table2
        insert into table3
        commit tran
end try

begin catch
        rollback tran
end catch
```

For most of the time above code works fine except once in a while(once per day or two) when some error occurs, the transaction does not rollback the changes from all 3 tables.

```
   begin try
            begin tran
            insert into table1----Rollback doesn't happen
            update table2--Rollback happens 
            insert into table3--Rollback happens 
            commit tran
    end try

    begin catch
            rollback tran
    end catch
```

Can anyone please can suggest something where I might be wrong or do I need to handle transaction in some another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't possible. Your analysis must be wrong. The only way a transaction would be partially rolled back would be if you were rolling back to a savepoint deliberately.

Comment: How have you determined that the rollback is/isn't happening in the way you describe. What information/logs, etc do you have that you believe points to this being the problem?

Comment: You said that for `update table2` and `insert into table3` rollback happens. It's not necessarily true. If the error occurs on `insert into table1`, execution jump right away to `catch` block. So it's not "rollback happens", rather "operation never performend".

Comment: It happened to me that an error rolled back the transaction but the batch continued to execute, now without transaction. I do not fully understand the exact conditions under which this can happen. Might be the case here.

Comment: @frikozoid in that case what I am not able to understand is why I still see the record inserted in table1 and not in other tables. Hence I assumed that rollback happened for table2 and table3 whereas not for table1.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : On checking the database, I can see that sometimes a record does exist in table1 but not in table2 and table3. Which could happen only if the rollback didnt work properly, right?

Comment: @Martin Smith : I am not setting any savepoints

Comment: Far more likely scenarios are a) that `WHERE` clauses attached to the second and third statements prevent them from adding rows in the first place, despite your expectations, b) that some other piece of code is affecting tables 2 and 3 afterwards, or c) that some other piece of code is just doing an insert into table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SET XACT_ABORT setting and what the error level inside the failing sql actually is

[How to make SET XACT_ABORT ON rollback the transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619292/how-to-make-set-xact-abort-on-rollback-the-transaction)