# SQL Server SET XACT_ABORT ON vs TRY...CATCH Block inside the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working on a game database. I have a stored procedure that is executed by the game client in case of teleportation, login, logout, death, etc processes. The game client is hardcoded and is not editable by me.

I am doing stuff in my procedure such as if the character logs in to the game, then add item to the character's inventory.

For each different types of process, I have `IF` blocks and also I have `TRY...CATCH` blocks in the each "IF" blocks to be able to handle with any errors in my procedure.

So, my question is that it does make any sense using `TRY...CATCH` blocks in this way? Or should I use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` statement instead of `TRY...CATCH`? Which one is better? By the way, the situation of occurrence of any error in `IF` block, the block have to be completely `ROLLBACK`.

Also, my procedure is highly executed by game client. There was almost 800 online character always moving in game and executed my procedure. It should be executed as possible as fast.

````
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_AddLogChar]
    @CharID  INT,
    @EventID TINYINT,
    @Data1   INT,
    @Data2   INT,
    @strPos  VARCHAR(64),
    @Desc    VARCHAR(128)
AS
    ---- !!! KILL PROCEDURE !!! ----
    IF (@EventID NOT IN (4,6,20))
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0;
    END

    ---- BATTLE ARENA | ACADEMY ----
    IF (@EventID = 20)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION TRAN_Battle_Arena

            -- Declaration of variables for battle area conditions
            DECLARE @CharInBattle VARCHAR(64) = SUBSTRING(@strPos, 15, 6)

            IF (@CharInBattle IN ('0x7edc','0x7edb','0x7ed7','0x7ed3','0x7dd3','0x7ada','0x7ad8','0x7ad7','0x7ad5','0x7ad4','0x79db','0x79da','0x79d8','0x79d7','0x79d5','0x79d4','0x74d6','0x73d7','0x73d6','0x73d5','0x73d4','0x72d7','0x72d6','0x72d5','0x72d4'))
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @KillingCharname VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@Desc,(PATINDEX('%(%', @Desc)) + 1, ((PATINDEX('%)%', @Desc)) - (PATINDEX('%(%', @Desc))) - 1)) 
                DECLARE @KilledCharname VARCHAR(64) = (SELECT CharName16 FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._Char WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CharID = @CharID)

                IF((@KillingCharname IS NOT NULL) AND (@KilledCharname IS NOT NULL))
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO LOG_BattleHonorRank (KillingCharname, KilledCharname, BattleRegion)  
                    VALUES (@KillingCharname, @KilledCharname, @CharInBattle)

                    UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD.._TrainingCamp 
                    SET GraduateCount = (GraduateCount + 1),
                        EvaluationPoint = EvaluationPoint + 5 
                    WHERE ID = (SELECT CampID FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._TrainingCampMember WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CharName = @KillingCharname)

                    UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD.._TrainingCamp 
                    SET EvaluationPoint = EvaluationPoint - 6 
                    WHERE ID = (SELECT CampID FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._TrainingCampMember WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CharName = @KilledCharname)
                END
            END

            COMMIT TRANSACTION TRAN_Battle_Arena
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT
                ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TRAN_Battle_Arena
        END CATCH

        RETURN 1;
    END

    ---- JOB SYSTEM ----
    IF(@EventID=6 AND (SELECT [Level] FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._CharTrijob WHERE CharID=@CharID)=7)
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION TRAN_Job_System

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Declaration of variables
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        DECLARE @Charname16 VARCHAR(64)=(SELECT Charname16 FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Char WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CharID=@CharID)
        DECLARE @traderJID INT=(SELECT UserJID FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._User WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CharID=@CharID)
        DECLARE @SkillID INT
        DECLARE @JobBuffLevel INT

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Check users have any information in SK_Silk or not, if not then begin to addition
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT JID FROM [SRO_VT_ACCOUNT].[dbo].[SK_Silk] WHERE JID=@traderJID)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [SRO_VT_ACCOUNT].[dbo].[SK_Silk] (JID, silk_own, silk_gift, silk_point) VALUES(@traderJID, 0, 0, 0);
        END

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Check users have any information in LOG_CharJobStatus or not, if not then begin to addition
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT CharID FROM SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharJobStatus WHERE CharID=@CharID)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharJobStatus (CharID, Charname, RestartCount, ObtainedSilk) VALUES(@CharID, @Charname16, 0, 0)
        END

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Begin to add reward silk, restart count, obtained silk & job coins information
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            UPDATE [SRO_VT_ACCOUNT].[dbo].[SK_Silk] SET silk_own=(silk_own+10) WHERE JID=@traderJID;
            UPDATE SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharJobStatus SET RestartCount=(RestartCount+1), ObtainedSilk=(ObtainedSilk+10), [Date]=GETDATE() WHERE CharID=@CharID
            EXEC SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._ADD_ITEM_EXTERN @Charname16,'ITEM_ETC_SD_TOKEN_02',4,0

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Check users restart count modulus, if modulus 10 equals to 0, then begin to add advanced elixir scroll
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        IF((SELECT (RestartCount % 10) FROM SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharJobStatus WHERE CharID=@CharID)=0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharJobStatus SET Obtained_Advanced_Elixir=(Obtained_Advanced_Elixir+1), [Date]=GETDATE() WHERE CharID=@CharID
            EXEC SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._ADD_ITEM_EXTERN @Charname16,'ITEM_ETC_VENUS_ADVANCED_ELIXIR_SCROLL',1,0
        END

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Check users restart count modulus, if modulus 5 equals to 0, then begin to add job buff
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        IF((SELECT (RestartCount % 5) FROM SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharJobStatus WHERE CharID=@CharID)=0)
        BEGIN

            IF EXISTS (SELECT JobID FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._TimedJob WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CharID=@CharID AND JobID IN (33791,33792,33793,33794,33795,33796,33797,33798,33799,33800))
            BEGIN
                DELETE FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._TimedJob WHERE CharID=@CharID AND JobID IN (33791,33792,33793,33794,33795,33796,33797,33798,33799,33800)
            END

            IF((SELECT BuffLevel FROM SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharJobStatus WHERE CharID=@CharID)<=10)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharJobStatus SET BuffLevel=(BuffLevel+1), [Date]=GETDATE() WHERE CharID=@CharID
            END

            SET @JobBuffLevel=(SELECT BuffLevel FROM SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharJobStatus WHERE CharID=@CharID)

            SELECT @SkillID=
            (CASE
                WHEN @JobBuffLevel=1 THEN 33791
                WHEN @JobBuffLevel=2 THEN 33792
                WHEN @JobBuffLevel=3 THEN 33793
                WHEN @JobBuffLevel=4 THEN 33794
                WHEN @JobBuffLevel=5 THEN 33795
                WHEN @JobBuffLevel=6 THEN 33796
                WHEN @JobBuffLevel=7 THEN 33797
                WHEN @JobBuffLevel=8 THEN 33798
                WHEN @JobBuffLevel=9 THEN 33799
                WHEN @JobBuffLevel>=10 THEN 33800
                ELSE 0
            END)

            IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT JobID FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._TimedJob WHERE JobID=@SkillID AND CharID=@CharID) AND (@SkillID>0))
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO SRO_VT_SHARD.._TimedJob VALUES (@CharID,0,@SkillID,(SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,'19700101 00:00:00:000',(SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,72,GETUTCDATE())))),0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
            END

        END

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Restart to users job level
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD.._CharTrijob SET [Level]=1, [Exp]=0, Contribution=0 WHERE CharID=@CharID

        COMMIT TRANSACTION TRAN_Job_System
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TRAN_Job_System
    END CATCH
    END
----==========================================================================================================----
    -------------------------------------------- SILKPERPERIOD -----------------------------------------------
    IF(@EventID=4 OR @EventID=6)
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION TRAN_SilkPerPeriod

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- For login state
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        IF (@EventID=4)
        BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT CharID FROM LOG_CharInOut WHERE CharID=@CharID)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO LOG_CharInOut (CharID,Char_Name,Is_Online,In_Date) VALUES(@CharID, (SELECT CharName16 FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._Char WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CharID=@CharID), 1, GETDATE());
            END
            IF EXISTS(SELECT CharID FROM LOG_CharInOut WHERE CharID=@CharID)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE LOG_CharInOut SET Is_Online=1, In_Date=GETDATE() WHERE CharID=@CharID
            END
        END

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- For logout state
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        IF (@EventID=6)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @SilkQuantity INT=1 -- Quantity of silk to be given within the specified period.
            DECLARE @ReqTime INT=60 -- The minimum required online period in minutes to be awarded for the silk reward.
            UPDATE LOG_CharInOut SET Is_Online=0, Out_Date=GETDATE() WHERE CharID=@CharID
            DECLARE @JID INT=(SELECT UserJID FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._User WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CharID=@CharID)
            DECLARE @LastOnlineTime INT=(SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,(SELECT In_Date FROM LOG_CharInOut WHERE CharID=@CharID),(SELECT Out_Date FROM LOG_CharInOut WHERE CharID=@CharID)))
            UPDATE LOG_CharInOut SET Last_OnlineTime=@LastOnlineTime, Total_OnlineTime=Total_OnlineTime+@LastOnlineTime WHERE CharID=@CharID
            DECLARE @TotalOnlineTime INT, @UsedOnlineTime INT;
            SELECT @TotalOnlineTime=Total_OnlineTime , @UsedOnlineTime=Used_OnlineTime FROM LOG_CharInOut WHERE CharID=@CharID

            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT JID FROM SRO_VT_ACCOUNT..SK_Silk WHERE JID=@JID)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO SRO_VT_ACCOUNT..SK_Silk (JID, silk_own, silk_gift, silk_point) VALUES(@JID, 0, 0, 0);
            END

            IF EXISTS(SELECT JID FROM SRO_VT_ACCOUNT..SK_Silk WHERE JID=@JID)
            BEGIN
                IF ((CONVERT(INT,@TotalOnlineTime-@UsedOnlineTime)/@ReqTime)>0)
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE SRO_VT_ACCOUNT..SK_Silk SET silk_point=silk_point+(CONVERT(INT,((@TotalOnlineTime-@UsedOnlineTime)/@ReqTime))*@SilkQuantity) WHERE JID=@JID
                    UPDATE LOG_CharInOut SET Used_OnlineTime=Used_OnlineTime+((CONVERT(INT,((@TotalOnlineTime-@UsedOnlineTime)/@ReqTime)))*@ReqTime) WHERE CharID=@CharID
                END
            END
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION TRAN_SilkPerPeriod
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TRAN_SilkPerPeriod
    END CATCH
    END
----==========================================================================================================----
    ---------------------------------------------- STAT RESET ------------------------------------------------
    IF(@EventID=6 AND EXISTS(SELECT CharID FROM SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharStat WHERE CharID=@CharID))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @RebirthCountForStat INT=(SELECT RebirthCount FROM SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharRebirth WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CharID=@CharID)
        DECLARE @MaxLevel TINYINT=(SELECT MaxLevel FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._Char WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CharID=@CharID)
        DECLARE @StatPoint SMALLINT, @RemainStatPoint SMALLINT

        SET @StatPoint=
        (CASE
            WHEN @RebirthCountForStat IS NULL   THEN @MaxLevel+19
            WHEN @RebirthCountForStat <= 5      THEN @MaxLevel+(@RebirthCountForStat*6)+19
            WHEN @RebirthCountForStat > 5       THEN @MaxLevel+49
            ELSE @MaxLevel+19
        END)

        SET @RemainStatPoint = (@MaxLevel*3)-3

        UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD.._Char SET Strength=@StatPoint, Intellect=@StatPoint, RemainStatPoint=@RemainStatPoint WHERE CharID=@CharID

        DELETE FROM SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharStat WHERE CharID=@CharID
    END
----==========================================================================================================----
    -------------------------------------------- REBIRTH SYSTEM ----------------------------------------------
    IF(@EventID=6)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @RebirthCount INT=(SELECT RebirthCount FROM SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharRebirth WHERE CharID=@CharID)
        DECLARE @Is_Active TINYINT=(SELECT Is_Active FROM SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharRebirth WHERE CharID=@CharID)

        IF(@Is_Active=1 AND @RebirthCount<=5)-- Rebirth Count Limitation-1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD.._Char SET
            CurLevel=1,
            MaxLevel=1,
            ExpOffset=0,
            SExpOffset=0,
            Strength=20+(@RebirthCount*6),
            Intellect=20+(@RebirthCount*6),
            RemainSkillPoint=0,
            RemainStatPoint=0
            WHERE SRO_VT_SHARD.._Char.CharID=@CharID

            DELETE CS FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._RefSkill RS INNER JOIN SRO_VT_SHARD.._CharSkill CS ON CS.CharID=@CharID AND RS.ID=CS.SkillID AND RS.ReqCommon_MasteryLevel1<=110 AND RS.ID NOT IN (1,70,40,2,8421,9354,9355,11162,9944,8419,8420,11526,10625)
            UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD.._CharSkillMastery SET [Level]=0 WHERE CharID=@CharID AND [Level]<=110

            UPDATE SRO_VT_LOG..LOG_CharRebirth SET Is_Active=0 WHERE CharID=@CharID
        END

    END
----==========================================================================================================----
--################################################################################################################```
````

Comment: There is too much going on in this one store procedure, first I would break this code into three separate stored procedures to handle event IDs 4, 6 and 20, then have a single TRY block where depending on the EventID value one of the three stored procedures get called and one CATCH block to rollback what ever the stored proc is called in the try block. The best practice is to do one thing in a stored procedure. The code is easier to manage and going forward it is easy to add more functionality if needed.

Comment: @M.Ali what about set xact_abort on vs try..catch ?

Comment: TRY CATCH always.

Comment: Must read [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) by Erland Sommarskog. You'd better use both `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and `TRY CATCH`.

Comment: I agree with @VladimirBaranov. The benefit of `XACT_ABORT ON` too is that it will rollback the transaction immediately in the case of a query timeout, where the `CATCH` block is not executed.

Answer (score 5):

You should used both. Let's create a simple table to demonstrate why and answer few fundamental questions.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[StackOverflow];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    [StackID] TINYINT
);
```

Now, execute the following statements (together):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (104);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (256);

SELECT [StackID]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];
```

You will get an error because the second insert is trying to insert value, which can not be stored in `TINYINT` type.

The ACID transaction has four properties defining it. The first is `Atomacity`:

> An atomic transaction is a set of events that cannot be
>   separated from one another and must be handled as a single unit of
>   work.

Knowing the above, one can think that the engine must rollback the two inserts, but **it will not. Why?**

Because in the context of the SQL Server, there are four methods for controlling transactions:

- auto-commit
- implicit
- explicit
- batch-scoped

The default one is `auto-commit`:

> Any single statement that changes data and executes by itself is
>   automatically an atomic transaction. Whether the change affects one
>   row or thousands of rows, it must complete successfully for each row
>   to be committed. You cannot manually rollback an auto-commit
>   transaction.

As a result - the above two inserts are two separate transactions where the first is committed and second not.

So, let's use `implicit` transaction applying `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` key words to defined the transaction body:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (105);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (256);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

SELECT [StackID]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];
```

So, one can thing that now the engine is going to rollback the two inserts, right? And of course - **it will not. Why?**

Because, when the [XACT_ABORT IS OFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (which is the default):

> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL
>   statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction
>   continues processing.

and when it is `ON`:

> .. if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire
>   transaction is terminated and rolled back.

That's what we need and if you try the code below, you can check this:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (105);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (256);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

SELECT [StackID]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];
```

So, is this enough? The answer is no - because:

> Compile errors, such as syntax errors, are not affected by SET
>   XACT_ABORT.

Here the first statement is committed, the second - not.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (106);

EXECUTE
('
InnnNSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (256);
');

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

SELECT [StackID]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];
```

The template I am using when CRUD are performed and I need to rollback some work in case of error is:

```
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN;
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;

    THROW; -- or log error or something else

END CATCH;

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

You can check the [Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017#includessdenoversionincludesssdenoversion-mdmd-isolation-levels) for more details.

Comment: So, can i use all ```IF``` blocks in between begin and commit transaction that you shared last template? Is it cause any performance issue? Also, some of ```IF``` blocks contain ```RETURN``` statment. Is it still required in your template or not?

Comment: It's generally better to leave in the `begin-commit` block only the CRUD operations. The preparation part can be between the `begin try` and `begin transaction` - for example, you can read some data, modify it, aggregate it and then to put only the `insert` part in the transaction block. You can safely use the 
template above wrapped in `IF` - of course the `SET` part can be leave in the beg and the end of the stored procedure only.

Comment: Here (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128535/in-what-cases-a-transaction-can-be-committed-from-inside-the-catch-block-when-xa#answer-128538) Max Vernon said in his answer that it is possible to get a situation when a ROLLBACK would not work inside the CATCH, so it is a sens to check XACT_STATE() in a CATCH block (Example C here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql#c-using-trycatch-with-xact_state).

Comment: Your example of why you need `TRY ... CATCH` is built on the claim that `SET XACT_ABORT ON` won't trigger on compile errors, but the docs for `TRY ... CATCH` also says that `TRY ... CATCH` [does not handle compile errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql).