# Write stored procedure so if one statement fails it should not effect the other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this procedure which basically insert data.

```
    Begin Transaction
                Insert into [dbo].Values
                    (
                        EQ



                    )
                    values 
                    (
                        @EQ


                    )

                  End

            --Set @STATUSRet= 'Created'
            --Set @ErrorRet= ''

        Commit Transaction
    End Try
    Begin Catch

        Set @STATUSRet= 'Failed'
        Set @ErrorRet= (Select ERROR_MESSAGE())

        Rollback Transaction

    End Catch
```

Now I want to add a piece of code that calls another database server and insert data into the table in that server i.e. remotely. That's ok I will do that but if that fails then that should not effect my current process of inserting the data as I have described above i.e. if the remote data insertion fails it should not effect the prior insert in any way and should return successfully to the calling application behaving like nothing happened.

Comment: how about adding `GO` after the insert?

Comment: @metal: can you elaborate please.

Answer (score 2):

The default method of controlling transactions is [auto-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57353124/1080354):

> Any single statement that changes data and executes by itself is
>   automatically an atomic transaction. Whether the change affects one
>   row or thousands of rows, it must complete successfully for each row
>   to be committed. You cannot manually rollback an auto-commit
>   transaction.

So, if the two inserts are not wrapped in explicit transaction this will be the behavior. If you have more code blocks, then you can use two separate explicit transactions blocks like this:

```
DECLARE @ExecuteSecondTransaction BIT = 0;

-- local database
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        -- CODE BLOCK GOES HERE

        SET @ExecuteSecondTransaction = 1;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 

   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END;

   -- GET ERRORS DETAILS OR THROW ERROR

END CATCH;

-- remote database
IF @ExecuteSecondTransaction = 1
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        -- CODE BLOCK GOES HERE
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 

       IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
       BEGIN
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
       END;

       -- GET ERRORS DETAILS OR THROW ERROR

    END CATCH;

END;
```

Comment: ok but what if the second block of code fails which is going to return a failure status to the calling application which relies on the status returned from the procedure.

Comment: because I am setting and sending some variables i.e. status, erro etc to the calling application which in turn use that to proceed further. So, if I add that in 1st block and executes successfully then would the calling app work or break if 2nd code block fails.

Comment: In the `CATCH` block you can `THROW` the error to `break` the application or to handle in it - the first commit is completed and no roll-backed. Or, the the `CATCH` block set `@Status = 'only first block is executed'` and handle the case in the application.

Comment: @Stackyboy you can use normal output parameters to inform your application of the execution status, so you don't have to break your stored procedure calling throw to report that status to your application, and preventing the execution of the posterior blocks.